# Paint Code - LeMans 1988

Tags: paint, paint-clearcoat

I have a Pontiac LeMans 1988, and I want repaint my car.
I have looked all over my car and I can't find the lower color code for my car. On the label of the service parts identification is only inscription: BASE/CLEAR COAT ENAMEL U9511.

[image]

What is the lower color code on my car?

Thanks for any info on this.

Comment: [Does this image help any?](http://www.plastikote.com/images/car_GM_plate_2.gif)

Answer (score 2):

Take this with a grain of salt because I am nowhere near an expert on car color matching, but I'm not sure if that portion of your car will have a color code. That's more a kind of body moulding piece (door skirt? typically plastic) that would have been added on after the painting of the car. My suggestion would be to see if a local paint shop could match the color for you and mix up a spray paint to match. Nowadays, some shops have tools that pretty accurately match a paint just by scanning the existing color with a little computer device. Best of luck to you!